# javascript - logaritmic scale in a slider

Tags: javascript, logarithm, input-type-range

I've searched here and there are a few similar questions but none really suit my needs.

I need to change the default slider behavior so that it allows a scale to be between 1 and 24 (day) with these values as possible values:

1
2
3
4
5
6
9
12
18
24

I don't even know where to start with this. Any help would really be appreciated as I am not really good at math and I don't know what formula I can use to achieve this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you post the slider code you're currently working with? It'd be pretty hard to help given the current info only. Thanks!

Comment: Use a 0-9 slider and a simple array to display the current value by using the slider value as index.

Comment: @Nick i'll post a codepen shortly

Comment: @ChrisG that's not actually a bad idea, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
let values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 18, 24];

let change = (e) => {
  document.querySelector('div').innerText = 'day: '+values[e.target.value];
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="9" step="1" oninput="change(event)" value=0>
<div>day: 1</div>
```

Comment: thanks this works as suggested by @Chris in the commend section above.

Comment: @Nick I dont read his comment because I work on code snippet - but yes he has similar idea that my